# random array values in AJAX POST

Tags: javascript, ajax

been driving my head through a wall to figure out how to get consistent results with the following code...I basically want to run 2 arrays of the same size for a sitewide find and replace via an API but the code seems to run through random values of the array - sometimes it will run the first value twice or will run through all 4 values in order for the search and replace - it's never the same...Anyone have any ideas how I can fix this code or is there a better way to code this?  Sorry if I'm not being clear...

```
var searchid;
var origArray;
var suggArray;
var orig = new Array();
var sugg = new Array();
var params;

orig = ["originalVal1", "originalVal2", "originalVal3", "originalVal4", "originalVal5", "originalVal6"];

sugg = ["replaceVal1", "replaceVal2", "replaceVal3", "replaceVal4", "replaceVal5", "replaceVal6"];

var counter = 0;

function getData() {

  if (counter === orig.length) {
    counter = 0;
  }

  gadget.ready().then(gadget.fetch).then(function() {

    params = {
      authorization_token: gadget.token,
      replace: true,
      path: "/mypath/aboutus/timelineGallery.pcf",
      site: "www",
      srchstr: orig[counter],
      rplcstr: sugg[counter]
    };

    $.ajax({
      async: true,
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://myapi/sites/findreplace",
      data: params,

      success: function(data) {

        searchid = data.id;

        $('p').append(searchid).append('<br />');

        counter++;
        if (counter < orig.length) getData();
      }
    });

  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are setting `async:true`, ajax call will run asynchronously so value of the var `counter` may not be updated in next call. You can either set async:false or get counter on ajax success as below,

```
counter = function () {
    var tmp = null;
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://myapi/sites/findreplace",
        data: params,
        'success': function (data) {
         searchid = data.id;

         $('p').append(searchid).append('<br />');

         tmp=counter++;
        }
    });
    return tmp;
}();
if (counter < orig.length) getData();
```

**Note ()** at second last line.

Comment: I've seen others add aysnc:false but in this case it makes no difference - same result...

Comment: @lespaulcus async:false means, your code will not proceed until ajax call completes where you are updating the counter. So you should get updated value there

Comment: setting async:false still produces random results unfortunately